# Converting the solr response (solrdocumentlist) to json (or xml)

Tags: json, solr

I am working on a search in which I am trying to convert the response from a `HttpSolrServer` to json format.  The response comes as a `SolrDocumentList`.  The code I have right now is:

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery(query);
solrQuery.setParam("wt", "json");  //doesn't affect the return format

QueryResponse rsp = solrServer.query(solrQuery);
SolrDocumentList docs = rsp.getResults();

return docs.toString();
```

When I print out the return, it comes back as:

```
{numFound=2,start=0,docs=[SolrDocument{cat=[electronics, camera], features=[3x zoop, 7.1 megapixel Digital ELPH, movie clips up to 640x480 @30 fps, 2.0" TFT LCD, 118,000 pixels, built in flash, red-eye reduction], id=9885A004, inStock=true, includes=32MB SD card, USB cable, AV cable, battery, manu=Canon Inc., manufacturedate_dt=Mon Feb 13 10:26:37 EST 2006, name=Canon PowerShot SD500, popularity=7, price=329.95, store=45.17614,-93.87341, weight=6.4}, SolrDocument{cat=[electronics, multifunction printer, printer, scanner, copier], features=[Multifunction ink-jet color photo printer, Flatbed scanner, optical scan resolution of 1,200 x 2,400 dpi, 2.5" color LCD preview screen, Duplex Copying, Printing speed up to 29ppm black, 19ppm color, Hi-Speed USB, memory card: CompactFlash, Micro Drive, SmartMedia, Memory Stick, Memory Stick Pro, SD Card, and MultiMediaCard], id=0579B002, inStock=true, manu=Canon Inc., name=Canon PIXMA MP500 All-In-One Photo Printer, popularity=6, price=179.99, store=45.17614,-93.87341, weight=352.0}]}}
```

for a search on `canon` using their example data.

If I instead do `return rsp.toString();` I get back the header information with it as:

```
{responseHeader={status=0,QTime=1,params={indent=true,q=canon\*,wt=xml,version=2.2}},response={numFound=2,start=0,docs=[SolrDocument{cat=[electronics, camera], features=[3x zoop, 7.1 megapixel Digital ELPH, movie clips up to 640x480 @30 fps, 2.0" TFT LCD, 118,000 pixels, built in flash, red-eye reduction], id=9885A004, inStock=true, includes=32MB SD card, USB cable, AV cable, battery, manu=Canon Inc., manufacturedate_dt=Mon Feb 13 10:26:37 EST 2006, name=Canon PowerShot SD500, popularity=7, price=329.95, store=45.17614,-93.87341, weight=6.4}, SolrDocument{cat=[electronics, multifunction printer, printer, scanner, copier], features=[Multifunction ink-jet color photo printer, Flatbed scanner, optical scan resolution of 1,200 x 2,400 dpi, 2.5" color LCD preview screen, Duplex Copying, Printing speed up to 29ppm black, 19ppm color, Hi-Speed USB, memory card: CompactFlash, Micro Drive, SmartMedia, Memory Stick, Memory Stick Pro, SD Card, and MultiMediaCard], id=0579B002, inStock=true, manu=Canon Inc., name=Canon PIXMA MP500 All-In-One Photo Printer, popularity=6, price=179.99, store=45.17614,-93.87341, weight=352.0}]}}
```

I know that with `HttpSolrServer` the response format can only currently be of xml or javabin (which I have set to xml).  This seems to have no impact on the actual returned results and their format.

I cannot seem to find anything about converting the response to a json.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well although it is an old question, I have come up with a similar issue and after digging the code, i was able to convert the response into json, although i am still sceptical about the speed and performance of the code in case there are too many reqs are coming..

so below is the piece of code that I wrote(I used the JSON lib from Jettison and ignore the stupid structure of the for loop):

```
QueryResponse qp = server.query(solrQuery);
SolrDocumentList docList= qp.getResults();
JSONObject returnResults = new JSONObject();
Map<Integer, Object> solrDocMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
int counter = 1;
for(Map singleDoc : docList)
{
  solrDocMap.put(counter, new JSONObject(singleDoc));
  counter++;
}
returnResults.put("docs", solrDocMap);
```

basically this will let you get results in json... solrj doesnt let you use any kind other than javabin **although you may set wt in the query explicitly**

hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

For what you are attempting to do, you do not need to use solrj library.  You can use CommonsHTTPClient to send query parameters over HTTP directly AND set 'wt=json' - to retrieve the response in JSON.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works

```
SolrDocumentList list =  new SolrDocumentList();
JSONArray jArray =new JSONArray();
QueryResponse result = solr.query(parameters);          
list=result.getResults();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(list.get(i));
     jArray.put(json);           
}
```

Also add the parameter `json.nl=map`.

Source: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON

Answer (score -1):

Import Gson and use its utility methods.

Comment: Please eloborate. I don't think that's a way to go.