# send json object in solr with java code

Tags: java, solr

i want display the results of the search in json format.
here is the code that i have..

```
HttpSolrServer solr= new HttpSolrServer(urlString);
//solr.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
SolrQuery parameters= new SolrQuery();
parameters.setQuery(search);
parameters.set("wt", "json");
parameters.set("qt", "/select");
parameters.set("df", "catch_all");

QueryResponse queryResponseResponse = solr.query(parameters);
SolrDocumentList resultList = queryResponseResponse.getResults();
```

Comment: Possibl Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351917/converting-the-solr-response-solrdocumentlist-to-json-or-xml

Comment: thanks,but when i write that code i take this error:Multiple markers at this line
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type SolrDocument to Map
 - Map is a raw type. References to generic type Map<K,V> should be 
  parameterized